# Access to ModuleID and PortalID in asmx webservice file in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asmx, dotnetnuke

I have an asmx webservice file in my DotNetNuke module.How can I access to PortalID and ModuleID in this asmx file . when I try this code that works fine in code behinde .ascx.cs file it return portalID=0 , ModuleID=1

```
 private Components.Setting _ModuleSettings;
 _ModuleSettings = new Components.Setting(PortalId, ModuleId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module settings require that you be within the context of a module.  An .asmx service is not going to have that level of context.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**
The below is still true, however the release of DNN 6.2 included the Services Framework which is specifically for the purpose of building web services in DNN.  Services Framework is a much better solution than rolling your own .asmx based service.

**/EDIT**

Since you are executing a web service call and not a DNN module that context is not provided for you.  However you can re-create it yourself.  To get the current portal settings

```
var domainName = Globals.GetDomainName(request);
var alias = PortalAliasController.GetPortalAliasInfo(domainName);

return new PortalSettings(-1, alias);
```

Since your are not truly in the context of a page, the ActiveTab will fallback to a default (unless you can replace -1 with the active tabId).

To get the module context you will need to pass in the moduleId and tabId to your service and then call:

```
var module = new ModuleController().GetModule(moduleId, tabId)
```

Comment: This answer is much more useful than the chosen one. Thanks!

Comment: @goughy000 check out DNN services framework, it is a much better solution than a hand rolled .asmx based service.

Comment: Unfortunately we are developing on an older portal which the customer will not upgrade :(