# Get session of DNN in aspx file

Tags: dotnetnuke

I write a standalone aspx file and upload it to DNN website. I add a html module and make an iframe to that aspx file. How I should check DNN user login or not in aspx file? I think there are something in Session but it is empty when I print it out on aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

The aspx file executes outside of DNN.  There is no context for you to work with.  A much better approach is to turn your .aspx into a .ascx and derive from PortalModuleBase as the start of a DNN module.  You can add a proper module to the page and permission the module as you see fit and DNN will take care of all the authentication and authorization details for you.

[A starting point for module development](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Module-Development.aspx)

I don't recommend it in this situation, but you can also emulate the approach I described for getting context in a web service.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9164573/51851

Answer (score 0):

If your aspx is within DNN's website you can simply use Request.IsAuthenticated to check if user is logged in or not.

But be warned, if you have friendly URL turned on - DNN 5x and above will hijack you aspx request.